# Assign image to PHP variable

Tags: php, image, list, variables

I would like to assign an image to a variable in a PHP script so that I can make the image appear when I want to it to, by declaring the variable.

```
$FoodList = array_unique($FoodList);
if (!empty($FoodList)) {
    foreach ($FoodList as $key => $value) {
        // The variable would go here, so that image would appear
        //next to each variable
        echo "<li>" . $value . "<li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

Comment: show us sample data for your `$foodList` array

Comment: And what is your `$value`? Image source?

Answer (score 1):

Either you assign
    $var = "img src="'your/pathto/image.ext'";

```
$var = "your/pathto/image.ext";
```

and echo it in html img code

The second method is more preferred

Comment: ext may be jpeg,gif whatever your file type is

Answer (score 1):

```
$FoodList = array_unique($FoodList);

if(!empty($FoodList)) {
    foreach ($FoodList as $key => $value) {
        //The variable would go here, so that image would appear
        //next to each variable
        $value = "<li>";

       //Maybe you'll only display an image is a certain condition is met? If so, then...
       if($condition == "parameter") {
           $value .= "<img src='path/to/img' alt='img' />";
       }

       $value .= "</li>";
       echo $value;
       unset($value);
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
echo "<li><img src='path_of_image/".$value."'/><li>";
```

Supposing that `$value` has the name of your image with extension of image.

Answer (score 0):

```
$FoodList=array_unique($FoodList); 
$img_path = 'images/example.jpg';
if(!empty($FoodList)) 
{
   foreach ($FoodList as $key => $value)
{

   echo "<img src='$img_path' />";
   echo "<li>".$value."<li>";

}
echo "</ul>";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 <?php

     $name="Adil";
     echo $name;
     $path="FB_IMG_1465102989930.jpg";
     for($i=0;$i<44;$i++)
     {
       echo($i.'<br>')     ;
       if($i==10)
       {
           echo ".$path.";
           echo "<img src ='".$path."'>";
       }
     }
 ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

please insert a space before your image name :-
Example:-

```
$image_name="myphoto.jpg";

$image_path="./upload/ ".$image_name;
```

here I add a space after `"./upload/(space)"`

Store the image path into your MySql database.

call it from your HTML page as:-

```
<img src= '<?php echo  $image_path;?>'width="200" height="200" alt=""/>
```